# Loop through the directories to get the image files

Tags: bash, image, find, mogrify

I have a directory which includes multiple sub-directories. I would like to go through the directories and subdirectories and find the jpg files and convert the size using mogrify command. I would like to do it as dynamic as possible that's why I wrote a script. The `$1` is the first argument that I pass through when executing the bash script. After running the script, it gives me an error about 'mogrify can not read [@]%'. I guess something is very wrong with my code and I am not mature in bash. Can anyone tell me how to do this script dynamically so that would be fast.

p.s: the name of jpg files are not in especial format...just bunch of numbers.

```
for folder in $1/*
do
    for file in "$folder"/*
    do
        if [  -e "${file[@]%.jpg}" ]; then
            mogrify -resize 112x112! "${file[@]%.jpg}"
        fi

    done
done
```

Comment: what do you think `${file[@]%.jpg}` should emit? you might just need `mogrify -resize 112x112! "${file}"`, but hard to be sure as you haven't specified what you need to work with `mogrify`. AND you're hoping for your process to be **fast**; don't get hung up on that, it is more important that your code doesn't cause any unfixable errors. Once you are certain about the safety of your code, then you can think about "what can it do to make it run faster", but given the constraints of your project, a shell `for` loop (what you have) is likely as fast as you'll be able to achieve (IHMO). Good luck.

Comment: The `[@]` bit is normally used to get all elements of an array, but `file` isn't an array, so this doesn't make sense. Also, the `%.jpg` part means "remove '.jpg' from the end", so if your script finds `somefolder/12345.jpg`, it'll try to run `mogrify` on `somefolder/12345` instead.

Answer (score 7):

If you're open to using `find`, then this becomes pretty easy:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
find "$1" \( -iname \*.jpg -o -iname \*.jpeg \) -print0 | while read -r -d $'\0' file; do
  # base="${file##*/}" $base is the file name with all the directory stuff stripped off
  # dir="${file%/*}    $dir is the directory with the file name stripped off
  mogify -resize '112x112!' "$file"
done
```

Put that in a file named `mymog.bash` then

```
$ chmod 755 mymog.bash
$ mymog.bash /some/dir
```

Notes:

- `!` is *special* to `bash`, so putting that in the single quotes make it "unspecial", passing it along to the `mogrify` command unmolested.
- The double quotes around `$1` and `$file` are needed in case a directory or file name has spaces in it. If you had a directory named `/Users/alice/my pictures` and didn't use the quotes, `mogrify` would get one argument named `/Users/alice/my` and another one named `pictures`.
- Make sure you use the `\(` and `\)` for `find`. That makes the whole condition ("match *.jpg" OR "match *.jpeg") apply to the action `-print0`.
- I used `find` 's `-print0` action which prints each matching file name with a null-terminated (zero-terminated) string. You can have filenames that have newline characters in the middle. This protects against that.
- `bash` 's built-in `read` command reads until a newline by default.  I used the `-d $'\0'` to make it read each "line" or "record" (filename) up to the null (zero) character at its end.  (Each ends with null because of the `-print0`.)

This solution (one of many) has two parts:

1. It uses the `find` utility to find (under the directory given) all files that end in `.jpg` or `.jpeg`, ignoring the case of the filenames.  [So it will match `.JPG` or even `\.JpEg`.]

   - It spits out one record for each file.
   - If you give it an absolute path like `/some/dir`, it will find `/some/dir/a.jpg` and `/some/dir/sub1/sub2/sub3/b.jpg`.
   - If you give it a relative path like `../../nearby/dir`, it will find `../../nearby/dir/c.jpg` and `../../nearby/dir/sub1/sub2/sub3/d.jpeg`.
2. The `find` part ends with the first `|` on that line. After that, it is a `bash` `while`…`do` loop.

   - The variable `file` takes on the value of each record spit out by `find`.
   - The loop (everything between `do` and `done`) runs once for each value that `file` takes on.
   - The two rows that start with `#` are comments.  They contain commands that are ignored (skipped). You can remove the `#` to have `bash` run those commands too.  I included them as examples in case you needed the directory part or just the filename part of the record.

Comment: thanks for your exact explanation. What is `file` in the `while read -r -d $'\0' file` ? Is it referring to jpg files? I just want to make sure I am getting it right

Comment: @user8034918 The `find` command outputs a list of .jpg and .jpeg files; the `while read ... file` part reads items (one at a time) from that list, and for each one it puts the filepath in the `file` variable and executes the `mogrify` command. So yes, `file` winds up referring to jpg files.

Comment: Thanks, @GordonDavisson. I edited the answer to add a little more explanation. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

```
find "$1" -type f -name "*.jpg" -exec mogrify -resize 112x112! {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `find` and a `while read` loop:

```
 find "$1" -type f -name '*.jpg' -print | while read fname
 do
    ....
 done
```

If your filenames may contain special chars like line feed, the use:

```
find "$1" -type f -name '*.jpg' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' fname
do
    ....
done
```

There are many more options to tune the search.